# why does jest have problems executing node module code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, jestjs

I have two modules.

One of them, "A", is ES5 with no babel. Its unit tests use mocha and chai and they complete successfully. The unit tests require a module, "M", during the testing. At this point, the code in the module is run. If it is not, the test fails. If i debug the execution, the "require('M')" jumps straight into the module.js require(path) and it loads/executes the code at the top module scope.

The other is ES6. It uses jest 19.0.2 and babel-jest 19.0.0, both currently the latest versions. It requires the same module but, unfortunately, the code is not run and the test fails. I've set "automock" to false explicitly. When I debug it, the "require('M')" stack is:

```
jest-runtime/build/index.js:requireModuleOrMock(from, moduleName)
jest-runtime/build/index.js:requireModule(from, moduleName, options)
jest-runtime/build/index.js:_execModule(localModule, options)
```

at this point it returns without running the module's code. The block is:

```
// If the environment was disposed, prevent this module from being executed.
if (!this._environment.global) {
  return;
}
```

Apparently the environment was disposed. Then requireModule() returns moduleRegistry[modulePath].exports. As a result, the top-level, module-scope code does not run and the test fails.

I should add that the failing code is run within a promise so it seems possible that the environment is released before the promise resolves. I have tried using:

```
let promise = ...
expect(promise).resolves.toBe(true);
```

but the execution path is unchanged.

If someone knows why this is occurring and how to ensure that the module code runs it would be appreciated.

Comment: `expect(promise).resolves` is not avaialble in v19.0.2, it will be officially added in v20. By this time you can use `jest@next` or [return that promise](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/asynchronous.html#promises) from test. If that wont help, it would be great to see a brief repro or at least test and module code.

Comment: thanks. I was going by the "return that promise" link that you mention. It will be a nice feature.